# How to copy multiple value if we passed multiple value

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface

I am using the below code to copy the folder but when I enter **a1,a2** then it's not working, only work with single platforms.

```
$publish="C:\Publish"
$finalpublish="C:\Publish\Final_Publish"
Write-host "a1,a2,a3" 
$platformvalue= Read-Host "Please enter Platform name which have dll in release, Please find above list for your reference"
IF($platformvalue -eq 'a1'){
Copy-Item $publish\a1 -Destination $finalpublish\a1 -Recurse
}
IF($platformvalue -eq 'a2'){
Copy-Item $publish\a2 -Destination $finalpublish\a2 -Recurse
}
IF($platformvalue -eq 'a3'){
Copy-Item $publish\a3 -Destination $finalpublish\a3 -Recurse
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Read-Host` only allows input as a simple string, but you seem to expect it to behave like an array with multiple values. So you either need to set up your script properly with **parameters** that you can pass your input to ([this is a simple introduction](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/how-to-use-parameters-in-powershell/)), or parse your `Read-Host` string first so that you can process each item.

For exmple, if you are putting commas between each item, you can split it into an array. You can quickly see how it works in the console.

```
> $platformvalue = (Read-host "prompt") -split ','
prompt: a1,a2,a3

# the input is now separate items if you output them in a Foreach-Item loop
> Foreach ($i in $platformvalue) { write-host "Output $i" }
Output a1
Output a2
Output a3
```

Once $platformvalue has been split into one or many items, you need to process them with `Foreach-Item` (that isn't strictly true if there's only one item, but you'd need more code to check - waste of time).

```
Foreach ($i in $platformvalue) {
    IF($i -eq 'a1'){
       Copy-Item $publish\a1 -Destination $finalpublish\a1 -Recurse
    }
  ...
}
```

By the way, if your variable will contain the entire string needed to accurately construct each path, you don't need the `If` statements.

For example, if `$platformvalue` is an array like `@("a1","a2")` (from splitting the `Read-Host` or whatever), and those strings are sufficent to construct your paths, you only need one copy statement:

```
Foreach ($i in ("a1","a2")) {
    Copy-Item $publish\$i -Destination $finalpublish\$i

    # 1st loop: $i = 'a1'
    # Result: $publish\a1 -Destination $finalpublish\a1
    
    # 2nd loop: $i = 'a2'
    # Result: $publish\a2 -Destination $finalpublish\a2
}
```

You'd only need all those `If`s if you're doing other modifications to the paths. If that's the case, I'd highly recommend using a `Switch` statement instead of a chain of `If`s.

Comment: Thank you @leem For Reviewing and Solution of my question. I really appreciate you.